# Using module without previously installing it

Tags: python, import, mysql-python

Firstly, thanks for will to help and reading this question. Few days ago I started working on an Python project which uses MySQLdb to connect to MySQL database. Problem is that I don't want my potential users to download this module to use this software, I wan't them to use one-click ready software. I've read many questions and topics here and while "googling" so I came to answer that I should put MySQLdb files in same folder as my .py file is. So I copied whole "MySQLdb" folder from this location "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb" and pasted it in same folder as my main.py file. So it looks like this now:

```
\main.py
\MySQLdb\constants
\MySQLdb\__init__.py
\MySQLdb\__init__.pyc
\MySQLdb\__init__.pyo
\MySQLdb\connections.py
\MySQLdb\connections.pyc
\MySQLdb\connections.pyo
\MySQLdb\converters.py
\MySQLdb\converters.pyc 
\MySQLdb\converters.pyo
\MySQLdb\cursors.py
\MySQLdb\cursors.pyc
\MySQLdb\cursors.pyo
\MySQLdb\release.py
\MySQLdb\release.pyc
\MySQLdb\release.pyo
\MySQLdb\times.py
\MySQLdb\times.pyc
\MySQLdb\times.pyo
\MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py
\MySQLdb\constants\__init__.pyc
\MySQLdb\constants\__init__.pyo
\MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py
\MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.pyc
\MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.pyo
\MySQLdb\constants\CR.py
\MySQLdb\constants\CR.pyc
\MySQLdb\constants\CR.pyo
\MySQLdb\constants\ER.py
\MySQLdb\constants\ER.pyc
\MySQLdb\constants\ER.pyo
\MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py
\MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.pyc
\MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.pyo
\MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py
\MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.pyc
\MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.pyo
\MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py
\MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.pyc
\MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.pyo
```

But when I try to import it like this:

```
import MySQLdb
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<iostream>", line 54, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to install MySQLdb directly into a "lib" folder on your project, like this: pip install -r requirements.txt -t <your_app_directory/lib>. Then, you can try to import it the way you are trying. Perhaps your copy missed something. Do no install it on the root of your package. Use a subfolder, like it is a module. If you are confused with the EGG structure, I recommend to take a look on a tool I made: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/machete/

Comment: @Lovato Then, how do I import something that is in subfolder? Like "import lib/MySQLdb" ?

Comment: If you try Machete, you will see that from start.py you can import anything inside the "modules" folder, "magically". The easy way is to see it in action, because its not only a single configuration. Folder needs to be a package, the import must be correctly written, and so on. The trick is `from lib import MySQLdb`

Comment: When I try to import it like "from lib import MySQLdb" it says "ImportError: No module named lib". Where am I making mistakes?

Comment: Sorry for double-post, forgot to tag you. @Lovato

Comment: Is lib folder brother of your .py, and you are on that path too? This is the first thing to check.

Comment: Yup, lib folder and .py are in the same folder.

Comment: I just created a.py, lib/b.py and lib/__init__.py (this one empty). Inside b.py, I put a function returning an int, and called it from a.py using from lib import b and print b.func(), and worked fine. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: @Lovato but I'm not trying to import another .py, I want to import whole module. I tried to do it using this line "from MySQLd import *" and that returns me error like "there is no module _mysql"...

Comment: You have to do `pip install mysqld -t lib`, then `touch lib/__init__.py`, and inside your py file, `from lib import mysqld`